# Layout Depth ...? How to adjust the layout hierarchies and layers ? (Android Studio)

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am working on my UI and I am beginning to question, how do you guys organize an app's layout hierarchies. In my XML file, whatever views/containers I include, usually the ones that are towards the end of the XML activity layout file are the ones placed on the top, while the ones written/placed first/earlier are usually placed towards the background.

Is there any attribute to control how these hierarchies/layers are ordered without having to worry much about the order in which they're placed in my XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ConstraintLayout. You can set constraints to the views regardless of the order in xml. This layout is also helpful building responsive and complex UI.

Comment: I am already using ConstraintLayout. The problem is that the views are stacked on top of each other depending on their order in XML, the last view in the XML is put on top, the first view in the XML is put on below. So I am questioning whether there is a way to stack them as I want, not according to their order in the XML.

Comment: In that case try giving z index or elevation for the view  @Sphax